# Can BitLocker be forced not to use the TPM when one is available?

Tags: windows-8, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I have a Dell D420 laptop. I want to encrypt my Windows 8.1 installation using BitLocker, however this computer appears to have a TPM installed and I do *not* want to use it. BitLocker keeps telling me that it will restart the computer to enable the TPM chip when I try to encrypt the drive, and seems to offer no alternatives. I tried to find information about this but I all the posts are about getting BitLocker to work when a TPM is *not* available, which involves just changing one entry in the Group Policy editor (which, by the way, I've tried and sadly it doesn't change anything).

**Can I use BitLocker without TPM when I have one available?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the checkbox "Allow Bitlocker without compatible TPM (requires password or start-up key on USB-drive)", try changing the other settings.

Check the box and Disallow using TPM. (At least it won't happen by accident then.)

Then disable the TPM component in Device manager and try again. Maybe you can trick your OS in ignoring the TPM.

*Side note: evaluate if mentioning why you would want to avoid using the TPM is relevant for you. Maybe somebody can reach that goal in another way. I speculate you don't want to create a bitlocker-dependency between the drive and the motherboard. I can speculate for what purpose; but that might be relevant to mention.*